# How to initialise value in controller with Angular js ?

Tags: angularjs

How to initialise   value inside controller function with AngularJS tried multiple time but not getting proper answer??

Comment: use $scope service to initialize variables and functions inside controller. I would suggest you to first go through some tutorial for angular js.Here is link to quickstart angular js basics- [link](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/)

Answer (score 3):

You can inject `$scope` in your controller function. Then you can define any variable inside `$scope`.

**Example**

```
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello';
}])
```

As you can see in the above example I have injected `$scope` to `TestController` and defined `message` variable inside it.

Note that all the variables defined in a controller scope are accessable by the view belonging to that controller. So you can access the value of `$scope.message` in your DOM as

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  {{message}}
</div>
```

On the screen you will see the text `Hello`